# How to print next line on Listbox

Tags: c#

I have been tearing my hair out with this problem, my ToString is repeating straight after each other rather than dropping to the next line.

as shown on this image, the second Event name should be on the line below.

[image: the problem]

```
//ToString method in Event Class
public override string ToString()
    {
        return "\nEvent name : " + m_evName + "\n Date :" + m_evDate + "\n";
    }

//print method in class
 public String PrintEvents()
    {
        StringBuilder retev = new StringBuilder("");

        foreach (Event e in m_events)
        {
            retev.Append(e.ToString() + "\n");
        }
        return retev.ToString();
    }



//Foreach that displays the text
private void cboListEv_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String SelectedVenue = cboListEv.Text;

        List<Venue> found = plan.selectVen(SelectedVenue);

        lstEvents.Items.Clear();

        foreach (Venue v in found)
        {
                lstEvents.Items.Add(v.PrintEvents());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this WPF or Winforms or ...?

Comment: Can you switch to WPF? If not, you may want to go with a custom control. I've done it a few times to get formatting in a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to print multiple text lines per `ListBox` item with the standard `ListBox`. Try using a `TextBox` instead, with `Multiline = true`, and in read-only mode. It will achieve a similar effect.

Beyond that, you'll need to draw up your own custom ListBox control with customized item templates that support multiple lines of data.

Comment: +1 Or use WPF if you MUST have a listbox. There is always the custom control option.

Comment: Well, I've just used the textbox option, and It's doing the same. :S Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: Did you set `MyTextBox.Multiline = true;` ? Also, it shouldn't matter, but try `\r\n` instead of `\n` (the former is Windows-style line breaks, while the latter is Unix-style).

Comment: Well, actually the problem is that it's finishing the line before it starts the new one, is there a way to start a new line with each new toString?

Comment: Since you modified your code, show us exactly what's being printed to the text box. I can't help further without seeing that. Also tell me what your desired output format is.

Comment: Ah thank you very much, that \r worked a treat. Simple little things that make all the difference. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`ListBox` items don't support multiline strings. However, you can make the `ListBox`'s `DrawMode` `OwnerDrawVariable`, then hook up something like the following to its `MeasureItem` and `DrawItem` events:

```
    internal int CountOccurrences(string haystack, string needle) {
        int n = 0, pos = 0;
        while((pos = haystack.IndexOf(needle, pos)) != -1) {
            n++;
            pos += needle.Length;
        }
        return n;
    }

    void ListBox1MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ItemHeight = (int)((CountOccurrences(((ListBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString(), "\n") + 1) * ((ListBox)sender).Font.GetHeight() + 2);
    }

    void ListBox1DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        string text = ((ListBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString();
        e.DrawBackground();
        using(Brush b = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor)) e.Graphics.DrawString(text, e.Font, b, new RectangleF(e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height));
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
```

-- will end up something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you provide the `PrintEvents()` method with the item collection of the `ListBox` you can have it add an item for every found event. Something like this:

```
//print method in class
public String PrintEvents(ObjectCollection items)
{
    foreach (Event e in m_events)
        items.Add(e.ToString());
}

//Foreach that displays the text
private void cboListEv_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String SelectedVenue = cboListEv.Text;

    List<Venue> found = plan.selectVen(SelectedVenue);

    lstEvents.Items.Clear();

    foreach (Venue v in found)
       v.PrintEvents(lstEvents.Items);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an `Events` property to the `Venue` class if not already there

```
public List<Event> Events
{
    get { return m_events; }
}
```

Then add the items like this

```
foreach (Venue v in found) {
    foreach (Event e in v.Events) {
        lstEvents.Items.Add(e);
    }
}
```